# Temple Run 2 Won't Give Me Credit for Today's Daily Challenge

Tags: temple-run-2

I am on day 250 for consecutive daily challenges.  Today's is Run 750M in One Run, Without Coins.  I've completed it 4 or 5 times, but it never will give me the chest, the reward, or credit for completing the challenge.  Of these, I want the credit most in order to keep my streak alive.  I've even tried to run it on a different map.  Even tried running 1000M with no coins and then dying shortly after with no coins.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I seem to have figured it out.  I exited the game, then closed the app from the open apps screen.  Then restarted and completed the challenge one more time. It must have been a glitch.